# Mostrar imagem na galeria

Tags: apache-cordova, mobile

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação mobile com **Apache Cordova**, onde faço download de algumas imagens, consigo fazer o download, mas as imagens não vão para a galeria. Já tentei salvar as imagens dentro da pasta Pictures, as imagens só aparecem no File Manager do meu Android, quando o celular está conectado no computador as imagens não aparecem.

```js
 function download(URL, Folder_Name, File_Name) {
        //step to request a file system 
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fileSystemSuccess, fileSystemFail);

        function fileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
            var download_link = encodeURI(URL);
            var ext = download_link.substring(download_link.lastIndexOf('.') + 1); //Get extension of URL
            var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root; // to get root path of directory
            directoryEntry.getDirectory(Folder_Name, { create: true, exclusive: false }, onDirectorySuccess, onDirectoryFail); // creating folder in sdcard
            var rootdir = fileSystem.root;
            var fp = rootdir.toURL(); // Returns Fulpath of local directory
            fp = fp + "/" + Folder_Name + "/" + File_Name; // fullpath and name of the file which we want to give
            // download function call                
            filetransfer(download_link, fp);
        }

        function onDirectorySuccess(parent) {
            //alert("Sucesso");
        }

        function onDirectoryFail(error) {
            //Error while creating directory
            alert("Unable to create new directory: " + error.code);
        }

        function fileSystemFail(evt) {
            //Unable to access file system
            alert(evt.target.error.code);
        }
    }
        function filetransfer(download_link, fp) {
            var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
            // File download function with URL and local path
            fileTransfer.download(download_link, fp,
                                function (entry) {
                                    alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                                },
                             function (error) {
                                 //Download abort errors or download failed errors
                                 console.log(error);
                                 alert(error.exception);
                                 alert("download error source " + error.source);
                                 //alert("download error target " + error.target);
                                 //alert("upload error code" + error.code);
                             }
                        );
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As imagens estavam sendo salvas, mas precisava do [Media Scanner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html) para indexar as imagens na galeria

**Media Scanner:**

> MediaScannerConnection fornece uma maneira para aplicações de passar
>   um arquivo de mídia recém-criado ou baixados para o serviço de scanner
>   de mídia. O serviço do MediaScanner vai ler os metadados do arquivo e
>   adicionar o arquivo para o provedor de conteúdo de mídia.

Como estava trabalhando com Apache Cordova/PhoneGap ele não fornece nenhum metodo nativo para fazer o refresh das imagens na galeria nativa, logo precisei procurar algum plugin para fazer este trabalho. Os plugins que encontrei foram:

[cordova-mediascanner-plugin](https://github.com/Xul13/cordova-mediascanner-plugin)
[MediaScannerPlugin](https://github.com/peteygao/MediaScannerPlugin/)

Ambos tem uma documentacao basica, entretanto utilizei o **cordova-mediascanner-plugin**.

Ao implementar este plugin, modifiquei somente meu metodo `filetransfer`

```
function filetransfer(download_link, fp) {
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        console.log(fp);

        // File download function with URL and local path
        fileTransfer.download(download_link, fp,
                            function (entry) {
                                //alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                                window.plugins.scanmedia.scanFile(fp, function (msg) {
                                    alert("Success ScanMedia");
                                }, function (err) {
                                    alert("Fail ScanMedia: " + err);
                                })
                            },
                         function (error) {
                             //Download abort errors or download failed errors
                             console.log(error);
                             alert(error.exception);
                             alert("download error source " + error.source);
                             //alert("download error target " + error.target);
                             //alert("upload error code" + error.code);
                      }
                    );

    }
```